# Pointer to char and printf

Tags: c, printf

I have the following problem I'm trying to print the return of this function and I'm having a segmentation fault and idk why

```
  char * cfnGetTime()
{
    char * szDate;
    struct tm *ptTime;
    time_t tTimeNow;
    
    /* Get date and time */
    (void)time(&tTimeNow);
    ptTime=localtime(&tTimeNow);
    (void)strftime(szDate, MAXPATHLEN, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", ptTime);
    
    return szDate;
}
```

when I do this

```
fprintf(gpfdLogFile, "%s%s - Comienza el proceso %s version %s\n", 
            __LINE__, cfnGetTime(), MODULO, LABEL);
```

Comment: `szDate` does not point to any memory location. You can use dynamic memory allocation: `char *szDate = malloc(MAXPATHLEN);` This creates a block of memory `MAXPATHLEN` bytes in size. Don't forget to later `free` that memory.

Comment: @Gabriela OhSatan Where does char * szDate point?

Comment: Why do you print the integer `__LINE__` with "%s"? Did you read the documentation for `fprintf`?

Comment: Another option is to pass an array to the function and use that: `char * cfnGetTime(char *szDate, size_t length) {...}` and then: `char buffer[MAXPATHLEN]; cfnGetTime(buffer, sizeof(buffer));` This way, there's no need to `free` the memory.

Comment: yeah you are right __LINE__ printf read it as an integer but why if I defined like this #define __LINE__     "-----------------------------------\n"

Comment: Or you could just use the `ctime` function: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/ctime.html

Comment: There is a built in macro `__LINE__`. You want to use your macro `LINE`.

Comment: haaaaaaaaaaa okok interesting thanks!

Comment: thank you @jwdonahue I will try to use it!